# How can I change the case of a Windows 7 user name?

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts

When I installed Windows this time around, I mistakenly entered my name as "myname". Seeing this annoys me every time I log on, and I would like to change this to "Myname".

Unfortunately, when I try to do this with the "User Accounts" control panel, it tells me that "there is already an account with that name". I imagine that usernames are not case sensitive for practical purposes - hence not allowing me to change it - but how can I change the capitalisation of the name that is displayed on the Welcome screen?

Comment: Change myname to Sam, then change it again to MyName... And you are correct, Windows does not care for the case of filenames, or usernames.

Comment: @AthomSfere duh, why didn't I think of that?! Just verified that it works. If you'd like to submit that as a full answer, I'll gladly accept it :)

Comment: LOL, done. You never know what someone has tried, but it seemed pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are correct that Windows does not care about the case of the user name. so myname and MyName are exactly the same.

You can get around the issues by changing the name twice though. Go to your Users and change the name to something random, like **Sam**, and then change the name again to **Myname**.